# Getting unable to locate element when switching to iframe?

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, frames

1. Trying to do login through facebook through rewards account after logging i get iframe to connect user with rewards account, am using window handler to locate the facebook pop up from that frame then it closes after login and i return to iframe but unable to locate an element on the parent window (iframe) when i switch back i get no such element
2. error is:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='errorData']"}

2. code used

   ```
   public void amberLoginWithFacebook(String username, String pass) throws InterruptedException {

   actions.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
   actions.driver.switchTo().frame(0);
   actions.clickOn(By.cssSelector(facebookBtn));
   Thread.sleep(2000);
   Set<String> handler = actions.driver.getWindowHandles();
   Iterator<String> loop = handler.iterator();
   String parentWindow = loop.next();
   String childWindow = loop.next();
   actions.driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
   if (actions.driver.getTitle().toLowerCase().equals(facebookWindowTitle)) {
   actions.setText(By.cssSelector(facebookEmail), username);
   actions.setText(By.cssSelector(facebookPass), pass);
   actions.clickOn(By.cssSelector(facebookLoginBtn));
   Thread.sleep(2000);

   }

   actions.driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
   // i get the exception here 
   if (actions.waitUntil(By.xpath("NonlinkedAccountError"), "presenceOfElement") != null)
   {setCountryCode(properties.getProperty("CountryCode"));
   setPhone(properties.getProperty("phone"));
   actions.clickOn(By.xpath(defaultBtn));
   actions.clickOn(By.xpath(enterEmail));
   setEmail(properties.getProperty("email"));
   }
   ```

[Screenshot for the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmFnM.png)

Comment: Your explanation is a bit unclear.  _What window is closing_ after you deal with the pop-up?  I assume you mean the child window closes?

Comment: @Brian yes the child window closes and i try to switch to the parent but i get the error window already closed though the parent is stil open ( the parent window is an iframe pop up which has a facebook btn that opens facebook login page (child window) and after you enter login details and click login this facebook page closes and parent pop up still open but unable to switch to it

Comment: Is the parent still in the window handles collection you created?

Comment: @Brian yes its stored their but when i switch to it i get the exception and window already closed .. its just cant locate the parent

Comment: I don’t see where you are calling, ‘driver.Quit()’.  Is there somewhere in the code you have not posted that you are?